# Prevent ZMQ c++ from calling rand()

Tags: c++, sockets, random, zeromq

I am using ZMQ 4.1.2 on Ubuntu 10.04.5 LTS.

I have a c++ program that seeds srand() with a fixed number, and then calls rand() ~100k times and exists.  I found that I was getting different random numbers when re-running the same program twice.

If I have a ZMQ socket open before I start my 100k draws it seems like the ZMQ library itself is calling rand() and messing up my repeatability.

```
this->context = new zmq::context_t(1);
this->socket = new zmq::socket_t(*this->context, ZMQ_PUB);
socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5556"); // offending line
```

All I need to do is omit calling socket->connect() and my calls to rand() behave deterministically.

Is this a bug (feature) in ZMQ?  Or does this also happen with the underlying TCP socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be using `rand_r` instead of `rand` so your usage doesn't conflict with other libraries using rand.
e.g.

```
unsigned int seed = YOUR_INITIAL_SEED;

for (int x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
{
    unsigned int r = rand_r(&seed);
    DoMyThing(r);
}
```

https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand

Comment: thanks. I can change my code to do this, but shouldn't the ZMQ library also be using rand_r ?

Comment: Everyone should be using rand_r.  :)

Comment: Really, no one should be using `rand` or `rand_r` for anything because on many systems they exhibit terrible biases and/or limited output ranges and trivially exhaustible seed states. But yeah, if you have to use one, `rand_r` is "safer".